# How can I get time from datetime in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, datetime

I fill my array array from database. the column called 'Yayina Başlama Zamanı' is a datetime column. I have tried this code for to get time from datetime object but it has occur "Call to a member function format() on string" error. How can I fix this error?

```
foreach ($sondakikaHaberler as $sonDakikaHaber){
            $dt = $sonDakikaHaber->yayina_baslama_zamani;
            $time = $dt ->format('H:i');
            $sonDakikaHaber['yayina_baslama_zamani'] = $time;
        }
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: is the datetime 0000-00-00 00:00:00 ?

Answer (score 3):

You must turn the date from your database (which is stored as plain text) into a [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) object first. So you'll get:

```
$dt = new DateTime($sonDakikaHaber->yayina_baslama_zamani);
```

Or if you're in a namespaced class, add a `\` in front of DateTime:

Or you can also add `use DateTime` in top of the page instead of adding `\` infront of `DateTime`

```
$dt = new \DateTime($sonDakikaHaber->yayina_baslama_zamani);
```

Then you can call the format method on it.

Regarding your secondary error (as posted in the comments), you cannot turn the result object `$sonDakikaHaber` into an array. So change:

```
$sonDakikaHaber['yayina_baslama_zamani'] = $time;
```

Into this:

```
$sonDakikaHaber->yayina_baslama_zamani = $time;
```

Comment: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array error has occured

Comment: @YağızMuğulkoç Show the code that creates `$sondakikaHaberler` It sounds like that is not what you think it is

Comment: @YağızMuğulkoç That is because of the line `$sonDakikaHaber['yayina_baslama_zamani'] = $time;`, `$sonDakikaHaber` is a result object from your database, not an array. Either use `$sonDakikaHaber-> yayina_baslama_zamani = $time` or use an actual array to store it in.

Answer (score 2):

you can use built-in date function,

```
date('H:i', strtotime("2021-04-29 03:30:00")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
  $time = date('H:i', strtotime($sonDakikaHaber->yayina_baslama_zamani));
```

make sure, your date field is not null and in correct format. The format() will throw error id both of null and incorrect formats. Also, you will have to convert it into datetime object if you want to use format() method.

Comment: I tried that method but Cannot use object of type stdClass as array error has occured

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to us `date()` and `strtotime()` remember the datetime is returned from the database as a string and not a PHP DateTime object, so you need to convert that string to a usable timestamp using `strtotime()`

As you are getting an array error maybe the code should be

```
$sondakikaHaberler->yayina_baslama_zamani = 
        date('H:i' strtotime($sondakikaHaberler->yayina_baslama_zamani) );
```