# Laravel SQL query midnight time not showing

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

I am making a schedule display system and it shows the schedules of ferries. my problem is if I dont put midnight time in order then query skips midnight time and displays morning instead

EXAMPLE:-

if i put data in order like this

1. 1:30 am
2. 6:30 am
3. 7:30 am

then the times show correctly, but if its not in order

1. 6:30 am
2. 7:30 am
3. 1:30 am

then the query skips the 1:30 am and goes straight to 6:30 to display.

Here is my laravel SQL Query:- if departure time is greater than current time then show the next available one

```
         DB::table('ferries')->groupBy('ferry_name')
        ->whereTime('departure_time', '>', Carbon::now()->toTimeString())
        ->whereIn('schedule_type', ['Weekday'])
        ->where('terminal_name', $terminal_name)->get()->all();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resukltsets are by nature unsorted yo you need to add a sorting order

This would sort ascending see [manual](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-sortby)

```
DB::table('ferries')->groupBy('ferry_name')
->whereTime('departure_time', '>', Carbon::now()->toTimeString())
->whereIn('schedule_type', ['Weekday'])
->where('terminal_name',$terminal_name)->orderBy('departure_time')->get()->all()
```

Comment: expected type 'object'. found 'array' thats the error when i write like that and when i write sortBy below whereTime i get Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sortBy()

Comment: try order by please

Comment: tried no errors nothing happens but weirdly when i tried another variable like ->orderBy('ferry_name', 'desc') it works

Comment: it is the type, that causes the problem, usually you have a datetime column, to sort by, may you also have one to try

Comment: yeah datetime works not sure how to remove date from datetime though and display time only instead

Comment: you need something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/36643294/5193536

Answer (score 0):

Used unique() instead of groupBy() then the orderBy worked not sure why.

```
$posts =  DB::table('ferries')->orderBy('departure_time', 'asc')
            ->where('departure_time', '>', Carbon::now()->toTimeString())
            ->whereIn('schedule_type', ['Weekday'])
            ->where('terminal_name', $terminal_name)->get()->unique('ferry_name')->all();
```